# The problem of YOLOv5 failing to play the generated .mp4 file from camera capture

Tags: python

[image]

The problem you are facing is that the .mp4 file generated by YOLOv5 from camera capture cannot be played.

"The issue lies in the inability to play the .mp4 file generated by YOLOv5 from camera capture. Can you please help me understand the reason behind this problem?"